# Detailed HTTP message with failing POST request _make_request in Requests package of Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, http, post, python-requests, diagnostics

Suppose a POST request fails

```
self._make_request(method="POST", json=dict(), path=f"test/buy")
```

returning an error such as 400 but you don't know what is happening behind the hood. You want to get detailed HTTP message to know the problem.

**How can you get detailed HTTP message with _make_request of Python 3 requests?**

Answer (score 0):

An option is to investigate things in debug mode like

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
```

where you see the request and its response witch each piece of information on a new line.